# Are if-if and if-elif defined as chained conditionals?

Tags: python, if-statement, chained

I know the difference between if-if vs if-elif statements, but do both belong to the definition of a chained conditional, or is the definition of chained conditionals only with if-elif statements correct?

Comment: I don't think "chained conditional" is an actual defined term.

Comment: I'd say if-elif yes but if-if no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right.
This is a chained conditional statement.

```
if 1 > 2:
    print("1 > 2")
elif 2 == 1:
    print ("2 == 1")
else:
    print("2 > 1")
```

And this is a sequence of conditional statements that are not chained together.

```
if 2 > 1:
    print("2 > 1")
if 3 > 2:
    print("3 > 2")
```